# Nodejs - Simple Echo Server not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I cannot figure out why I cannot write out to the socket. I don't know if my event listeners are created properly or not. I am trying to learn Nodejs and I am new to javascript.

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');
var channel = new events.EventEmitter();

channel.on('join', function(socket){

    this.on('broadcast',function(data){
        socket.write(data);
    });

});

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){

    socket.on('connect',function(){
        channel.emit('join',socket);

    });

    socket.on('data',function(data){
        data = data.toString();
        channel.emit('broadcast',data);
    });
});

server.listen(8888);
```

Comment: `net.createServer` gets passed in a connection in the callback.  Your callback for `createServer` means you have a connected client, so you can just "join" there.  Then you can listen for `data` events like you already are.

Comment: See: http://hackintoshrao.com/2013/02/01/guide-on-writing-socket-programs-using-nodejs/

Comment: @Joe I was experimenting creating a custom event emitter ,but it seems that channel.emit('broadcast',data) is not being called when data is send to the server.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener      using this first to get the basics.And for that i think you havenot install broadcast from npmjs.org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `connect` event for a socket is only emitted in my understanding, when you establish a connects as a client; you're doing a server here however.  When the callback inside `net.createServer` is called, you are already connected to the socket, so even if the `connect` event was emitted, you'd be subscribing to it with `socket.on('connect', ...` too late.

In turn, since the callback of `connect` is not called, you are never emitting the `join` event on the event channel and never registering the `broadcast` event handler, and the `socket.write` statement is never called.  As pointed out, a few `console.log` statements would help you figuring out, what code actually gets executed and narrowing down the issue.

You can fix this by simply removing the `socket.on('connect', ...` and doing what it's doing right way in the outer function, i.e.,

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket){   
    console.log("connect!");
    channel.emit('join',socket);

    socket.on('data',function(data){
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Use console.log to see what's going on, and maybe a slightly simpler example first, e.g.:
http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener

Also, consider using http://socket.io/, which makes a lot of the networking stuff easier and more robust. With socket you can do something like:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888, {log : true});
```

and get a lot of nicely formatted debugging information about the server and what it's doing (note the `{log: true}` that enables this debugging information).

Comment: Using console.log is a valuable tip/comment, but not an answer to Nikita's question.  Considering that he's just learning learning node.js, using WebSockets (with socket.io) instead of pure TCP (where you can test with telnet etc.) also doesn't make things easier for him, IMHO.